How do you quickly gain friendship in Pokérogue?
Friendship in Pokérogue gives you candies for your starters when you hit a certain threshold, and I know that battling gives friendship, but is there any other way to gain friendship?
I'm looking for the fastest way to gain friendship, so that I can earn more candies with the Pokémon I like.

The only other way of gaining Friendship points is through using Rare Candies. Note that Rarer Candies and Candy Jars does NOT have any influence whatsoever on the amount of Friendship gained, however Rarer Candies will give Friendship points to every Pokémon in your team.
All this information can be found on the official PokéRogue wiki in this page
